# Parsing moment() object as filename with ngCsv and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, momentjs

I'm trying to properly format an object to be inserted as a filename in ngCsv.

ngCsv uses the `filename="name.csv"` attribute, but I need to use an object with two properties as filename. The object comes from `ng-model="dates"`, has two momentJS properties and looks like this:

{-startDate---2014-11-05T21-00-00.000Z-,-endDate---2014-11-05T21-00-00.000Z-}

I've tried to use `{{dates}}` as filename like follows:

```
<button ng-csv="filteredRecords" 
        filename="{{dates}}.csv">Download results as CSV
</button>
```

But then the resulting file is obviously called `{-startDate---2014-11-05T21-00-00.000Z-,-endDate---2014-11-05T21-00-00.000Z-}.csv` because the dates have no format.

The desired result would be something like `23-12-2014 - 25-12-2014.csv`.

I've also tried to format them before in the attribute like so:

```
<button ng-csv="filteredRecords" 
        filename="{{ moment(dates.startDate, 'DD[/]MM[/]YYYY') - moment(dates.endDate, 'DD[/]MM[/]YYYY')}}.csv"">
            Download results as CSV
</button>
```

But that doesn't work either. Any idea on how to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

The solution from Davin works perfectly.

I've tried to make it work further by including also in the filename other fields from the filter.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-1">
   <input class="form-control" placeholder="Car" ng-model="search.car">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
   <input class="form-control" placeholder="Driver" ng-model="search.driver">
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" 
        type="button" 
        ng-csv="filteredRecords" 
        filename="{{ createCsvFilename(dates, search) }}">
           Download
</button>
```

And the JS:

```
$scope.createCsvFilename = function(dates, search) {
    var startMoment = moment(dates.startDate);
    var endMoment = moment(dates.endDate);
    var filterCar = search.car;
    var filterDriver = search.driver;
    return startMoment.format('DD-MM-YYYY') + ' - ' + 
           endMoment.format('DD-MM-YYYY') + 
           ' - Car_' + filterCar  + ' - Driver_' + filterDriver + '.csv';
}
```

It also works, and I get the desired filename, but I get some errors in the console, because before applying any filter (date range or otherwise), both `startDate`, `endDate` and `search` are undefined.

Any workaround for this? Is just to leave it as neat as possible, because as I already said, it delivers the expected results.

Comment: Does this work: `{{ moment(dates.startDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY') - moment(dates.endDate).format(DD-MM-YYYY')}}.csv`?

Comment: No, it gives me 0.csv as a result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use `moment` inside the interpolation `{{ }}`.  Angular only runs a very cut down version of JavaScript inside.

So, your best bet is to make a method that will return you the csv file name.  Example below.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.dates = {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date()
  };   
  
  $scope.createCsvFilename = function(dates) {
    var startMoment = moment(dates.startDate);
    var endMoment = moment(dates.endDate);
    
    return startMoment.format('DD-MM-YYYY') + ' - ' + endMoment.format('DD-MM-YYYY') + '.csv';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div>
      {{ createCsvFilename(dates) }}
    </div>
    <button ng-csv="filteredRecords" 
        filename="{{ createCsvFilename(dates) }}">
            Download results as CSV
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. I've implemented it and developed it a bit further. I just get some errors in the console because all variables are undefined till the user filters the list by date or by any other property (see Edit). Any quick workaround to get rid of the errors? If it's a mess I'd leave it like this as it delivers what I need.